# combining pandas data frame rows into a single vector

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have pandas data frame with one column.

I want to concatenate each value of column such that it turns into a single vector.

```
data_frame =            0
                0   [55,75,97]
                1 . [47,51,107]
```

result should be [55,75,97,47,51,107]

I tried np.vstack(), np.column_stack() etc., nothing worked out.
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

This will create a list from your column.

```
l = []
[l.extend(e) for e in df[0].values]
l # your list
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can do:

```
sum(dataframe[0],[])
```

or

```
[item for row in dataframe[0] for item in row]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the columns in a separate list as below:

```
print (df['0'].tolist())
[[55,75,97], [47,51,107]]
```

So, we can combine them to a single list in this way.

```
print ([a for b in df[0].tolist() for a in b])
[[55,75,97,47,51,107]]
```